# Using a DiffGram in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a web portal in Java that supports incremental changes to an XML document.  I really like the [diffgram](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172088(VS.71).aspx) technology in .Net, but I must use Java for this project.  Is there a Java library that can modify an XML document object using diffgrams?  We will likely be using JAXB, but I can always marshal data to build the original XML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything like this in Java, at least, not based on diffgram. Maybe have a look at [Open Source XML Diff Written in Java](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-xml-diff-in-java) for xml diff solutions in Java. Or [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=java+xml+diff) for more alternatives.

Actually, this project looks interesting: [fc-xmldiff](http://code.google.com/p/fc-xmldiff/) (Fuego Core XML Diff and Patch Tool). Never tested personally though.